# Retrieve a column name that has today date with respect to the specific row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have a pandas dataframe read in from Excel, as below. The column labels are dates.
Given today's date is 2020-04-13, I want to retrieve the C row values for next 7 days.
Currently, I set the index and retrieve the values of C, when I print rows I get the output for all the dates and their values of C.
I know that I should use `date.today()`. Can someone let me know how to capture the column of today's date (`2020-04-13`) for the C row? I am beginner to python/pandas and am just learning the concepts of dataframes.

```
input_path = "./data/input/data.xlsx"   
pd_xls_obj = pd.ExcelFile(input_path)   
data = pd.read_excel(pd_xls_obj,sheet_name="Sheet1",index_col='Names')   
rows = data.loc["C"]
```

[image]

Comment: Use this - ```data.loc["C", [datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]]``` to fetch the "C" row for today's date.

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Index(['2020-04-20'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]",I get this error and 2020-04-20 column is present in my sheet

Comment: Can you paste the value of `print(df.columns.tolist())` here

Comment: Please tag this [tag:pandas], and mention 'pandas' and 'dataframe' in the body. Dataframes are specific to pandas, they are not a native Python thing.

Comment: It's unorthodox to use the date as *column labels*, instead of as *row index*, and since pandas dtypes go by column not by row, it means pandas won't correctly detect the column label type as date, rather than string, and hence comparison operators on it won't work properly. Instead, you should transpose the dataframe immediately at read-time: `pd.read_excel(...).T` Then, make sure the dtypes are correct.

Comment: Please post the data as text, not images, so we can copy it and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to do it, is to load the data from the workbook with headers and then do (in words) something like: Show me from ***data[column: where date is today][row: where data['Names'] is equal to 'C']***

i would not go for the version, where you use a column (which anyway only has unique values) as index..

code example below; I needed to use "try: _____ except: ", because one of your headers is a String and the ".date()" would through an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


INPUT_PATH = "C:/temp/data.xlsx"

pd_xls_obj = pd.ExcelFile(INPUT_PATH)

data = pd.read_excel(pd_xls_obj, sheet_name="Sheet1")

column_headers = data.columns

# loop though headers and check if todays date is equal to the column header
for column_header in column_headers:
    # python would throw you an Attribute Error for all Headers which are not
    # in the format datetime. In order to avoid that, we use a try - except
    try:
        # if the dates are equal, print an output
        if column_header.date() == datetime.date.today():
            # you can read the statement which puts together your result as
            # follows:
            # data[header_i_am_interested_in][where: data['Names'] equals 'C']
            result = data[column_header][data['Names'] == 'C']
            print(result)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unorthodox in pandas to use the date as column labels, instead of as row index, and since pandas dtypes go by column not by row, **that means pandas won't correctly detect the column label type as 'datetime', rather than string/object**, and hence comparison and arithmetic operators on it won't work properly, so you'll have to do lots of unnecessary avoidable manual work and conversions to/from datetime. Instead:

**You should transpose the dataframe immediately at read-time**:

```
data = pd.read_excel(...).T
```

**Now your dates will be in one single column with the same dtype, and you can convert it with `pd.to_datetime()`.**

Then, make sure the dtypes are correct, i.e. the index's dtype should be 'datetime', not 'object', 'string' etc. (Please post your dataset or URL in the question to make this reproducible).

Now 'C' will be a column instead of a row.

You can access your entire 'C' column with:

```
rows = data[:, 'C']
```

... and similarly you can write an expression for your subset of rows for your desired dates. Waiting for your data snippet, to show the code.

Comment: Ya,I have pasted the dataset at the top and trying with your suggestion now.